# Replacing only single value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

While working on the Adventure Works database to learn few things, I encountered this issue, that in in one column of the Inventory Table, the ReStocking Frequency column has entries of the days as 30days, etc. Few of them are in the format 30d. I want all the values with the number of days followed by the word "days" i.e., 30days, 40 days etc in a consistent way. Replacing values does not work here. I have also attached the screenshot. Please help how can I achieve this in Power Query.
[image]

Tried the Replace Values, but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Values did not work because it is more suited for exact matches

Instead, you can use Add Column > Custom Column :

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each if Text.EndsWith(Text.Trim([RestockingFrequency]), "d") then 
    Text.Replace(Text.Trim([RestockingFrequency]), "d", " days") 
else 
   [RestockingFrequency])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get numbers from text then you can use:

```
Text.Remove(Text.Lower([RestockingFrequency]), {"a".."z", " "})
```

As a Custom Column:

```
#"Add FrequencyDays" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "FrequencyDays", each Text.Remove(Text.Lower([RestockingFrequency]), {"a".."z", " "}), type number)
```

Or updating existing column:

```
#"Update Frequency" = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"RestockingFrequency", each Text.Remove(Text.Lower(_), {"a".."z", " "})} )
```